# Pass each object in JSON array to query

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm running query that looks like this:

```
var ready_data= $.getJSON('URL HERE', function (data) {
var id_value= data.rows.map(function (row) {
  return [row[1]+","+ row[2]];
});
```

The var id_value comes back in my console log with something like this:

```
Array[1]]0: Array[1]0: "34.154321,-118.349126"length: 1__proto__: Array[0]1: Array[1]2: Array[1]3....
```

I'm only showing part of what's returned for clarity. But basically, I get back an array for each item that matches my query criteria from my getJSON (they're map coordinates).

What I want to do is put each of these arrays (one at a time) into a query and get back the results. Right now, I'm using this:

```
 $.each(id_value,function(data) {

  var key='MY API KEY'
          var table ='TABLE NUMBER'
           var sql = "SELECT COUNT() from " + table +
              " WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(coordinates,CIRCLE(LATLNG("+id_value+"), 16093 ))";
              url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?key=" +     encodeURIComponent(key) + "&sql=" + encodeURIComponent(sql) + '&callback=?';
 $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
              $('#info2').append((data.rows ? data.rows[0] : 0) );
          });
});
```

This doesn't work because it builds a query string with every single pair of coordinates in the same query instead of one query per array.

How should I be doing this so that I've got a functioning .each loop (or something totally different)?

Comment: That part: `... LATLNG("+id_value+"), ...` looks like a genuine mistake to me. Ought to be `... LATLNG("+data+"), ...`, no?

Comment: @Tomalak That didn't make a difference unfortunately. This is close though. It passes one object at a time, but it looks like it's passing the value from a different column instead of the combined object from the two columns (1,2). It's passing what's in column 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your code should look something like this:

```
$.getJSON('URL HERE').done(function (data) {
    $.each(data.rows, function (row, i) {
        var coords = [row[1], row[2]].join(",");

        $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?callback=?", {
            key: "MY API KEY",
            sql: "SELECT COUNT() from TABLE NUMBER WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(coordinates, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + coords + "), 16093))"
        }).done(function (result) {
            console.log("received result " + i, result);
            // deal with the result (remember that they don't arrive in predictable order)
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // don't forget to add error handling
        });
    });
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     // don't forget to add error handling here, either
});
```

This sends N requests to the Google API, one for each row in your original array and runs a callback for each of the N results.

Note how you don't need to deal with `encodeURIComponent()` if you simply pass an object with your parameters to jQuery.

---

EDIT: To orchestrate multiple asynchronous HTTP requests and run a certain function when *all* of them are done, use `$.when()`. I strongly recommend reading into jQuery's [Deferred semantics](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), they are an indispensable tool and you should take the time learning how they work.

```
$.getJSON('<QUERY URL HERE>').done(function (data) {
    // create an array of pending Ajax requests
    var xhrRequests = $.map(data.rows, function (row) {
        var latlng = [row[1], row[2]].join(",");
        return $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?callback=?", {
            key: "API KEY",
            sql: "SELECT COUNT() from TABLE NUMBER WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(coordinates, CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + latlng + "), 16093))"
        });
    });

    $.when.apply($, xhrRequests).done(function () {
        // this runs after *all* requests have completed successfully
        // arguments contains the results in original request order
        var counts = $.map(arguments, function (xhrResult) {
                // each of the results will be an array [data, status, jqXhr]
                var data = xhrResult[0];
                return data.rows ? data.rows[0] : 0;
            }),
            total = 0;

        // output to the screen, calculate a total, whatever you need
        $.each(counts, function (i, count) {
            total += count;
            $("<div>", {text: count}).appendTo("#info2");
        });

        $("<div>", {text: total}).appendTo("#info2");
    })
    .fail(function (jqXhr, status, textStatus) {
        // this runs as soon as *one* of the requests has failed
        // react to the HTTP error here
        console.log(jqXhr, status, textStatus);
    });
});
```

I've created a more advanced, more modularized, live example over here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/y54tkpz7/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. If I console.log coords, I get just a comma and that's it.

Comment: Without seeing what `data` looks like, exactly, I can't tell you what's wrong. And I'm sure if you look very closely at how `data` looks like, you could figure it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it working based on your answer and comments. Unfortunately, I'm stuck again. I thought it would be trivial to add each of the counts as they came in and I was only appending to the div just to see if I could get the values. What I really want is to add them together to get a total, but can't figure that out. Any ideas? What I'm getting returned are just single numbers (not arrays).

Comment: @jonmrich See modified answer. Also have a look at the jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. The issue I'm having now is an error for all the queries because it's adding "callback=%3F". The error says that there's a problem with that part of the query. If I remove the entire callback part, the query works, but then I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined" for the line that comes after this:  var data = xhrResult[0];. Not sure if this is because I removed the callback or if this would cause an error on its own (i.e., something else is wrong).

Comment: @jonmrich Adding the `callback=?` back to the URL seems to do the trick. My mistake. (Again, also to look at the fiddle, too. It's quite a bit different from the code in my answer.)

Comment: That fixed the callback issue, but now getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined" This is referring to the lines "var counts = $.map(arguments, function (i, xhrResult) {" and "var data = xhrResult[0];". All of the calls are working, but it's stuck here. Doesn't seem like "arguments" is defined anywhere. And thanks for the fiddle. Just to clarify...are these all independent modules or would I use it all at once?

Comment: `arguments` is always defined inside a function. (Try again.) I don't know what you refer to with *"these"*. The fiddle simply is a more abstracted version of the code in this answer.

Comment: Thanks...got it working using the code above (still struggling with the fiddle for now, but I'll get it). Had to convert "count" into a number in order to have the numbers actually add. Changed the one line to this: "total += parseInt(count,10);". Is there a better way to do this (i.e., change the counts as they come in to strings or get them as numbers)?

Comment: That depends on the JSON you get from the Google server. Your code simply uses `data.rows ? data.rows[0] : 0` to grab the count from the response, my code has the exact same line. It works in my fiddle since those mockup Ajax requests return actual numbers, I suspect the real ones return strings. To convert to number unconditionally I'd suggest the `.then()` call in `getStoreCount()`: `.then(function (data) { return data.rows ? parseInt(data.rows[0], 0) : 0; })`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the response from @Tomalak, I was able to figure it out (or at least something that's working for me).

```
$.getJSON('<QUERY URL HERE>').done(function (data) {
 var coors = data.rows.map(function (row) {
    return [row[1],row[2]];
});

$.each(coors, function (index,value) {
   var key='API KEY'
          var table ='TABLE NUMBER'
           var sql = "SELECT COUNT() from " + table +
              " WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(coordinates,CIRCLE(LATLNG("+value+"), 16093 ))";
              url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?key=" + encodeURIComponent(key) + "&sql=" + encodeURIComponent(sql) + '&callback=?';

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
$('#info2').append(data.rows ? data.rows[0] : 0);
          });
```

This adds each of the counts (of stores within 10 miles) for each set of coordinates to my div "info2".